# HeaderFooterView of UITableView not stretching according to size class width

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I have a tableview with a custom header i make from a nib file.

The size class of the nib file is Any x Any, but the width of the Header does not stretch to fit on iPhone 6 & iPhone 6Plus.

Here's how i make the `HeaderFooterView`

```
let headerCell = UINib(nibName: "TeamCheckHeaderTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
tblTeamCheck.registerNib(headerCell, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: TeamCheckHeaderTableViewCell.description())
```

In `viewForHeaderInSection`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerCell = tblTeamCheck.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier(TeamCheckHeaderTableViewCell.description()) as! TeamCheckHeaderTableViewCell

    return headerCell
}
```

Here's how it looks on a iPhone 5

[image]

Here's how it looks on a iPhone 6

[image]

The same with 6Plus, It seems like the width of the `HeaderFooterView` is constant `320`.

Comment: Do you create headerCell in viewDidLoad? If so move it in viewWillAppear and call its layoutIfNeeded method

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `headerCell.layoutIfNeeded()` to `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, but probably not the best - **Still open for better solutions**.

I hardcoded the width of the header cell to be 414 in the .xib file - Which is the width of iPhone 6 Plus.

Then programmatically calculate the position of the center label, and set the constraint so it will be centered, no matter which iPhone screen it is.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerCell = tblTeamCheck.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier(TeamCheckHeaderTableViewCell.description()) as! TeamCheckHeaderTableViewCell

    //Calculate the diff and set the new constraint
    let tableViewWidth = tableView.frame.size.width
    let headerCellWidth : CGFloat = headerCell.frame.size.width
    let diff =  headerCellWidth - tableViewWidth
    headerCell.centerConstraint.constant = diff/2

    return headerCell
}
```

I created the constrains as a variable in the `TeamCheckHeaderTableViewCell`

```
@IBOutlet weak var centerConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the class type of the item inside your xib. You might have used a UITableViewCell. Replace it with a UIView and it will start stretching.